# WooCommerce new user - Admin notification issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

In my website registration page, when a new user register a notification will be sent to the user and admin saying a new user registered. The notification mail to the user works fine, but admin wasn't able to get any notification with the default WordPress notification option. So, I am using better notification plugin to notify the admin. Even though the plugin works fine, I couldn't able to add any new user registration details such as name or mail id.

With the better notification plugin, I can only able to get notification like:

"New user registered"

I can't able to view any of the new user details.

I want a notification something like this:

"New user registered
Name :xxx
E-Mail:xxx@yymail.com"

Can someone help me with this issue, if there is any plugin or method which will solve my issue please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You can communicate with the plugin developer's. As this seems to be the plugin's issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce New Customer Admin Notification Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343928/woocommerce-new-customer-admin-notification-email)